# How to read a mdash character in C++ fstream

Tags: c++, fstream

I currently am trying to have my program read a text document of the Gettysburg address and print it out into the command prompt. The issue I have ran into is are — (mdashs) in the text that the program is printing out as ΓÇö. I attempted to add a part of the code to read for the mdash but it does not ever come back as a mdash so it never changes what to be printed. Here is what I have so far.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char asciiChar;
    ifstream readChar;
    readChar.open("Gettysburg.txt");

    while(!readChar.eof())
    {
        readChar.get(asciiChar);
        if (!readChar.eof()){
            if (asciiChar!='—'){
                cout << asciiChar;
            }
            if (asciiChar=='—'){
                asciiChar=151;
                cout << asciiChar;
            }
            }
        }
    readChar.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Any help on how to properly detect this value would be appreciated!

Comment: View the file in a hex editor (or run it through hexdump and/or xxd) and show us what's actually in the file.

Comment: Sounds like encoding confusion. [Start with The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

Comment: You'll need to know what encoding the text document is in, what encoding your source code is in, and what encoding your output device uses.  If all three of those are Unicode UTF-8, you're golden -- you'll just have to learn how to work with Unicode UTF-8 strings in your C++ code.

Comment: Note: Looping on EOF is almost always a bug. It looks like you have worked around part of the bug with the if not EOF, but a more simple solution is `while (readChar.get(asciiChar))` Read a character, test the stream state, and enter the loop body if good.